# Get path to servlet container deploy/webapps folder

Tags: servlets

From within the service method of a servlet, I can get the path to the web application's root folder with `getServletContext.getRealPath("")`, e.g. */tomcat/webapps/MyWebApplication*, but is there any way I can get the path to */tomcat/webapps/* or optionally a specific other web application like */tomcat/webapps/MyOtherWebApplication* (without resorting to hacks like substracting the context path)?

(Using only TomCat as an example, should work across all servlet containers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServletContext` has a `getContext(String)` method ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29)) that return the `ServletContext` corresponding to another webapp, which you could then call `getRealPath()` on.  However, the appserver's security model might forbid this, so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Path to Tomcat dir (tomcat/bin):

```
File inputFile = new File("file.xml"); // tomcat_dir/bin/file.xml
```

Path to other Tomcat directories, "webapps" for example:

```
File inputFile = new File("../webapps/file.xml"); // tomcat_dir/webapps/file.xml
```

Nice way to get rid of the absolute paths :)